# Problem using tables in itextsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf-generation, itext

i am trying to generate a pdf file using itextsharp in asp.net c#.

I came across table concept in itextsharp n i am trying to use it ie my application. I am having the following problem while using tables.

[image]

The pdf cell which contains `Name of treasery` the word treasery comes on next line. I am setting width for each cell. if i increase the width than also no changes come. The gap which is shown using arrow in below image remain as it is al the time. Why is that gap?How to remove that gap?

I want a dotted line as a border to only one cell. how to do that?here is my code

```
    PdfPTable line6table = new PdfPTable (3);
    float[] width = new float[] { 2.5F, 1.5F, 3.0F };
    line6table.SetWidths(width);
    line6table.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
    line6table.WidthPercentage = 100.0f;
    line6table.SpacingBefore = 6.0f;

    PdfPCell a1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Head Of Account"));
    a1.Border = 1;
    a1.Indent = 2.2f;
    a1.PaddingTop = 5.0f;
    line6table.AddCell(a1);

    PdfPCell a2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("CHARGED"));
    a2.Border = 1;
    a2.PaddingTop = 5.0f;
    line6table.AddCell(a2);

    PdfPCell a3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Name of the treasry"));
    a3.Border = 0;
    a3.Indent = 15.0f;
    a3.RightIndent = 0.0f;
    a3.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
    line6table.AddCell(a3);


    pdfDocument.Add(line6table);
```

Please help me to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
line6table.WidthPercentage = 100.0f;
```

This did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the width of the column.

Comment: That doesn't help either. I had done that before posting my question. The width of  other two cells gets decreased if i increase width of third cell. The gap remains as it is.